# True or false. A subset of a spanning set is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> True or False. Let $S=\{v_1, v_2, ...., v_p\}$ be a subset of a vector space $V$. If $\text{span}(S)=V$ then some subset of $S$ is a basis for $V$.

My answer: False. Because if $\text{span}(S)=V$ then ALL subsets of $S$ should form a basis for $V$.

Comment: Let $V$ be two-dimensional.  $\{v_1\}$ is a subset of $S$.  Is $\{v_1\}$ a basis for $V$?

Comment: @LA Paragon You are not answering the question. The question is whether there exists a subset which is a basis, not whether some subset isn't. In any case your assertion that all subsets of $S$ are a basis is false.

Comment: hmm so its false but im still confused as to why a subset of is not a basis for V

Comment: what is your definition of basis?

Comment: largest spanning set of linearly independent vectors

Comment: Just for reference, if it is true that "All X are Y" and it is true that some X exists, then it is also true that "Some X are Y." So if your assertion about "all subsets of $S$" were true, it would be a proof that the original statement was **true**. As it happens, your statement was false, but the next time you want to use the fact that "All X are Y" to contradict the assertion that "Some X are Y," don't. It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality let $B = \{v_1,\dotsc, v_n\}$ be linearly independent and for every $k=n+1,\dotsc,p$ the set $B \cup \{ v_k \}$ is linearly dependent. That is, 
$$ v_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i,k} v_i. $$
Now, for $x = \sum_{i=1}^{p} x_i v_i \in V$ we have
$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i v_i + \sum_{k=n+1}^{p} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_k \alpha_{i,k} v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( x_i + \sum_{k=n+1}^{p} x_k \alpha_{i,k} \right) v_i. $$
That is, $B$ spans $V$ and $B\cup \{ x \}$ is linearly depending.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true and we can construct the basis recursively.
Suppose that $v_1\neq0$ and define $B_1=\{v_1\}$. Next, for each $2\leq j\leq p$, define $$B_j=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
B_{j-1},& \mbox{if $v_j\in span(\{v_1,...,v_{j-1}\})$}\\
B_{j-1}\cup\{v_j\},& \mbox{if $v_j\notin span(\{v_1,...,v_{j-1}\})$}
 \end{array}\right. .$$
Now we will prove by induction that

> For each $1\leq j \leq p$,  $B_j$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_j\})$.

It surely holds for $j=1$.
Now suppose that $B_j$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_j\})$ and let us see that $B_{j+1}$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_{j+1}\})$.
We consider two cases:
**Case 1:** $v_{j+1}\in span(\{v_1,...,v_{j}\})$.
Then $span(\{v_1,...,v_{j+1}\})=span(\{v_1,...,v_{j}\})$ and by definition  $B_{j+1}=B_j$, so by the induction hypothesis $B_{j+1}=B_j$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_{j+1}\})=span(\{v_1,...,v_j\})$.
**Case 2:** $v_{j+1}\notin span(\{v_1,...,v_{j}\})$.
Then $B_{j+1}=B_j\cup\{v_{j+1}\}$. First, since $span(B_j)=span(\{v_1,...,v_j\})$, it is clear that $span(B_{j+1})=span(\{v_1,...,v_{j+1}\})$. So, in order to see that $B_{j+1}$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_{j+1}\})$, it only remains to prove that $B_{j+1}$ is linearly independent.
We write $B_j=\{u_1,...,u_k\}$. Then $B_{j+1}=\{u_1,...,u_k,v_{j+1}\}$. Suppose that 
$$ \alpha_1u_1+...+\alpha_ku_k+\alpha_{k+1}v_{j+1} =0.$$
Since $v_{j+1}\notin span(\{v_1,...v_j\})=span(B_j)$, we must have $\alpha_{k+1}=0$. Then, we get $\alpha_1u_1+...+\alpha_ku_k=0$, and since $B_j=\{u_1,...,u_k\}$ is linearly independent, it follows that $\alpha_1=...=\alpha_k=\alpha_{k+1}=0$.

> Then, for $j=p$ the set $B_p\subset \{v_1,...,v_p\}$ is a basis for $span(\{v_1,...,v_p\})=V$